# Why do mapped drives only reappear after logging out and back in, and not after a reboot?

Tags: windows-7, network-shares

I work in a corporate environment, where we use mostly Windows 7 Professional computers, though some legacy applications are still being run on Windows XP.

We have security in place on the network not to allow access to network resources to computers that are not members of Active Directory.

When logging in, our users get their home folder and a common network drive mapped to H: and F:, respectively.

Sometimes, this does not happen, and the drives are not mapped. The solution is to have the user log off, and back in to Windows. If they reboot, the drives remain unmapped.

Does anyone know why this may be?

Comment: Which method are you using for drive mapping?

Comment: We have this issue at our corporate environment as well.  Our AD accounts all run a logon.bat that is "supposed" to map everything, but sometimes it just doesn't.  I've manually put something in the start up folders of our Public Users that maps the drives at logon to counter the issue.

Comment: @week: The setup described by TKEyi60 is pretty much what we have, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to revisit this question today, and after a bit of research found the following:

Windows 7 has a nasty habit of not looking for a network connection early in the boot process. If it tries to map the drive before it finds the connection, mapping will fail.

Source: http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/103088-mapped-drives-do-not-reappear-after-logon