# Every time I boot into Windows 10, my network mappings are disconnected

Tags: windows-10, network-shares

I don't think it's ever not happened.

I'll start an application that depends on the drive being mapped, and it will fail.
I'll open windows explorer and see the drive there with the typical red X. It then is clever enough to load the free space on the share - but it still won't actually work until I go into the share in explorer. Then it is mapped correctly.

Is there a way I can either automate that process every startup, or even better, actually have my drives map properly?

Comment: Have you seen this: https://superuser.com/questions/1026424/why-wont-my-mapped-drive-persist-for-elevated-user-after-reboot

Comment: I hadn't until now, despite some vigorous searching. It's a shame people have to resort to such 'innovative' workarounds for something that should really be standard behavior...

Comment: The keyword I used for search was `persistent`..